# How to convert SAS code logic if first.variable to PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, sas, row-number

I'm trying to convert the following SAS logic to PySpark, but I'm not getting the expected output.

```
if first.loan then seq_id = 0;
seq_id+1
```

The current dataset:

| loan | module |
| --- | --- |
| 743 | 455 |
| 4490 | 795 |
| 1101 | 235 |
| 1101 | 335 |
| 1101 | 435 |
| 3471 | 898 |

The expected dataset:

| loan | module | seq_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 743 | 455 | 1 |
| 4490 | 795 | 1 |
| 1101 | 235 | 1 |
| 1101 | 335 | 2 |
| 1101 | 435 | 3 |
| 3471 | 898 | 1 |

Comment: See the second post here and it also explains why this is difficult in PySpark. https://towardsdatascience.com/adding-sequential-ids-to-a-spark-dataframe-fa0df5566ff6

Comment: I faced a similar challenge and created a function that replicates the SAS logic. check out [here](https://github.com/samkart/SASUtilityMacros/blob/master/firstDotSAS.py). of course, you can also choose to use `row_number()`

Answer (score 2):

For the first value in the group, you assign `seq_id=0` and then you immediately change it using `seq_id+1`. Subsequent values in the group one-by-one get changed using `seq_id+1`, so effectively you create row numbers in every group.

In Spark, this can be done using [`row_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.row_number.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number) window function.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(743, 455),
     (4490, 795),
     (1101, 235),
     (1101, 335),
     (1101, 435),
     (3471, 898)],
    ['loan', 'module'])

w = W.partitionBy('loan').orderBy('module')
df = df.withColumn('seq_id', F.row_number().over(w))

df.show()
# +----+------+------+
# |loan|module|seq_id|
# +----+------+------+
# | 743|   455|     1|
# |1101|   235|     1|
# |1101|   335|     2|
# |1101|   435|     3|
# |3471|   898|     1|
# |4490|   795|     1|
# +----+------+------+
```